# Spring: @Valid always returns False

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring Framework. I'm trying to get @Valid to work. Data Binding is happening properly but not the validation. hasErrors() is always returning False in the Controller class. Please see below code.

I'm utilizing Spring 4.1.3 and Hibernate validator 6.0.16.

**Context xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

     <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
     </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties"/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.personal, com.documentum" />
</beans>
```

**Controller**:

```
package com.personal.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.personal.search.model.SearchForm;
import com.personal.search.service.SearchService;

@Controller
public class SearchController {

    private SearchService service;

    @Autowired
    public SearchController(SearchService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchHome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new SearchForm());
        return "search/search";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchResults(@Valid SearchForm searchForm, BindingResult errors, Model model) {
        if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(searchForm.getObjectName());
            model.addAttribute(service.getResults(searchForm));
        }
        return "search/search";
    }

}
```

**View**:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sf:form method="POST" commandName="searchForm">
        <sf:errors path="*" />
        <label>Enter Object Name:</label>
        <sf:input path="objectName"/><sf:errors path="objectName" /><br>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </sf:form>
    <h3>For your search term "${searchForm.objectName}" below are the results: </h3>
    <c:forEach items="${searchResultList}" var="searchResult" >
        <li>
            <div>
                <span>
                (<c:out value="${searchResult.objectName}" />,
                <c:out value="${searchResult.title}" />)</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

**Model**:

SearchForm Model:

```
package com.personal.search.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class SearchForm {

    @NotBlank
    private String objectName;

    public SearchForm() {
    }

    public SearchForm(String objectName) {
        this.objectName = objectName;
    }

    public String getObjectName() {
        return objectName;
    }

    public void setObjectName(String objectName) {
        this.objectName = objectName;
    }

}
```

SearchResult Model:

```
package com.personal.search.model;

public class SearchResult {

    private String objectName;
    private String title;

    public SearchResult() {
    }

    public String getObjectName() {
        return objectName;
    }
    public void setObjectName(String name) {
        this.objectName = name;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }



}
```

**Service**:

```
package com.personal.search.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.personal.search.dao.SearchDAO;
import com.personal.search.model.SearchForm;
import com.personal.search.model.SearchResult;

@Service
public class SearchService implements ISearchService {

    private SearchDAO dao;

    public SearchService() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public SearchService(SearchDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SearchResult> getResults(SearchForm searchform) {

        return dao.getSearchObjects(searchform);

    }



}
```

**DAO**:

```
package com.personal.search.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.documentum.com.DfClientX;
import com.documentum.fc.client.DfServiceException;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfClient;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfCollection;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfQuery;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfSession;
import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfSessionManager;
import com.documentum.fc.common.DfException;
import com.documentum.fc.common.IDfLoginInfo;
import com.personal.search.model.SearchForm;
import com.personal.search.model.SearchResult;

@Repository
public class SearchDAO {

    private String repository;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private IDfSessionManager sessionMgr = null;

    public SearchDAO() {

    }

    @Autowired
      public SearchDAO(
              @Value("${docbase.repository}") String repository,
              @Value("${docbase.user}") String userName,
              @Value("${docbase.password}") String password) 
      {
          this.repository = repository; 
          this.userName = userName; 
          this.password = password; 
          System.out.println(repository + " " + userName + " " + password);
      }


    /**
     * Creates a  IDfSessionManager
     */
    private IDfSessionManager getSessionManager()
    {
        // create a client object using a factory method in DfClientX
        DfClientX clientx = new DfClientX();
        IDfClient client;
        IDfSessionManager sessionMgr = null;
        try {

            client = clientx.getLocalClient();

            // call a factory method to create the session manager
            sessionMgr = client.newSessionManager();

            addIdentity(clientx, sessionMgr);


        } catch (DfException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sessionMgr;

    }

    private void addIdentity(DfClientX clientx, IDfSessionManager sessionMgr)
    {
        // create an IDfLoginInfo object and set its fields
        IDfLoginInfo loginInfo = clientx.getLoginInfo();
        loginInfo.setUser(userName);
        loginInfo.setPassword(password);
        if (sessionMgr != null) {
            if (sessionMgr.hasIdentity(repository))
            {
                sessionMgr.clearIdentity(repository);
            }
        }
        try {
            sessionMgr.setIdentity(repository, loginInfo);
        } catch (DfServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public IDfSession getDBSession() {

        IDfSession sess = null;

        // Get a session using a factory method of session manager.
        try {
            sess = sessionMgr.getSession(repository);
        } catch (DfServiceException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTraceAsString());
        }

        return sess;
    }

    public void releaseDBSession(IDfSession sess) {

          sessionMgr.release(sess);

    }


    public List<SearchResult> getSearchObjects(SearchForm searchform) {
        List<SearchResult> lst = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();
        this.sessionMgr = getSessionManager();
        IDfSession sess = null;
        try
        {
            sess = getDBSession();
            if (sess != null) {
                IDfQuery query = new DfClientX().getQuery();
                String dqlStr = "select object_name, title from dm_sysobject where object_name like '%"  + searchform.getObjectName() + "%'";
                System.out.println(dqlStr);
                query.setDQL(dqlStr);
                IDfCollection co = query.execute(sess, IDfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);
                while (co.next()) {
                    SearchResult searchresult = new SearchResult();
                    searchresult.setObjectName(co.getString("object_name"));
                    searchresult.setTitle(co.getString("title"));
                    lst.add(searchresult);
                }
                if (co != null)
                    co.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sess != null)
                releaseDBSession(sess);
        }
        return lst;
    }

}
```

I expect the hasErrors() output to be True.

Comment: SearchForm  field  objectName  @Null?   Isn't   @NotNull?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Yes, I changed it to @NotBlank.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you have defined the validation as,

```
@Null
@Size(min=1, max=30)
private String objectName;
```

Check if when you submit the request to controller the objectName has `NULL` value or empty string?

For String you must use `@NotBlank` and not `@Null`

Comment: The objectName value is an empty string. I changed it to @NotBlank and still same behavior. errors.hasErrors() is still returning false.